# Meaning of "half-crown enclosure"

Tags: idioms

In the novel "Brighton Rock", Graham Greene refers to a "half-crown enclosure" in the context of horse racing.

My guess is that it may refer to a type of horse race where half-crown refers to a betting limit, or the size of the purse or payout.

Alternatively, the phrase may refer to a type of race track.

I tried searching the internet but found no explanation except for a few vintage postcards.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Marc. This is a free combination (like 'intelligent boy') rather than a collocation ('strong tea') or compound ('camomile tea'). It might as well be a 'five-bob enclosure' or a 'two-and-ninepence enclosure' – or 'the ten-bob stands'. The premodifier merely states the admission price to the stated restricted part of the racecourse.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A *half-crown* is an obsolete, pre-decimal British coin. A crown was worth 5 shillings old money (= 25p now) so a half-crown was worth 2s 6d or 12.5p decimal. There were 8 of them to the pound sterling.

A *half-crown enclosure* would have been a spectator area where the admission fee was a half-crown, probably with a better view of the track or finish line.

I can find 2 references to this phrase where the meaning can be inferred from the context
[A report of the 1907 Brooklands 1st Race Meeting](https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/1907_Brooklands_1st_Race_Meeting)  7th paragraph 
There is also a photograph of a [spectator area entitled *half-crown enclosure*](https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/File:Im070713Auto-Brook02.jpg)

and 
[an 1882 report of a horse race meeting in Australia](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/91466102)

Comment: Sounds plausible. Do you have a link to back your horse so to speak...

Comment: I've found two references that give this interpretation from their context.<br>. One is from a very old (1882) horse race report in an Australian newspaper
[https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/91466102]  and the other from a 1907 report of the opening meeting at Brooklands motor racing track [https://www.gracesguide.co.uk/1907_Brooklands_1st_Race_Meeting] 7th paragraph and a photograph ow what appears to be a spectator enclosure

Comment: I'd suggest adding those links to your answer. But you should probably double-check the 2nd link at least. I got an error notification when I clicked it.

Comment: I also did a search, but only came up with one link and the info is different. You want it? If not I'll post as a possible alternative answer.

Comment: @SConroy Thanks for the comment, I've done as you suggested. by all means add to the answers, I'd be interested in seeing a different result.

Comment: I half wonder reading those links if the 'betting' element merged into the spectator element, but I think my horsey research is done for the day.

Comment: I am (just) old enough to remember the half crown. It was a very common coin, and so it would have the same sense as *dime* in American usage. Indeed, it was the pre-decimal equivalent of the modern 10p, which was only 20% less in value. We don't do things fast in the UK. The [florin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florin_(British_coin)) was introduced as a step towards decimalization in 1867 but the [half crown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_crown_(British_coin)) continued in use until 1970. Although it was tecnically half of a crown, it should be noted that the crown was obsolete.

Comment: As Mark Hubbard's answer shows, the half-crown enclosure was the cheapest. It would have been better than no enclosure but it was clearly not prestigious. Even in those days 12½p was not a lot of money.

Comment: @David Robinson A **half crown** (or, colloquially, a half dollar) wasn't the equivalent of a 10p, that was a **florin**. There were 20 shillings to the pound, a shilling became 5 new pence (instead of 12 old ones) so there were 10 florins to the pound. The half crown was worth two shillings and sixpence so was, as you say, worth 12.5 new pence. The half crown wasn't replaced by a new coin but the florin was replaced by the 10p. In Greene's time half a dollar was a fair bit of cash, enough to buy four or five pints of beer. It would probably be the equivalent of about £10 to £15 by now.

Comment: @BoldBen I meant that *half crown* was the equivalent in the sense that it was a common name for describing a certain amount of money, in the same sense as *bob*, *quid* and *tanner*, and *dime* and *nickel* in the US. Although the florin existed alongside the half crown, it never really caught on in the lexicon, as the following ngram shows, where I have had to multiply the incidence of *florin* by 500, even to make it visible on the same chart. A *florin enclosure* would sound very odd - it would have been called the *two-shilling enclosure*.

Comment: [ngram showing *half crown* and *florin* (x500) in British English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=half+crown%2Bhalf-crown%2C%28florin+*+500%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28half%20crown%20%2B%20half%20-%20crown%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28florin%20%2A%20500%29%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2C(half%20crown%20%2B%20half%20-%20crown)%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C(florin%20*%20500)%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @DavidRobinson I'll go with it being a close equivalent  of the dime but you said it was the equivalent of the 10p, which it wasn't, that was the florin or, colloquially, "two bob bit".

Answer (score 8):

Here is an example from the 1907 Brooklands 1st Race Meeting (an automobile race, in this case):[image: 1907 Brooklands 1st Race Meeting]

Comment: I think that rather confirms that it was the admission price to the viewing area. I don't think there were any bookmakers at British motor racing circuits so it wouldn't be the price of a bet.

Comment: Peter Jennings - FT Harris ("Long Tom") was a famous bookmaker who operated at Brooklands in the 1920s: "Many of your readers will recollect the difficulty I had in persuading the Brooklands authorities that it was to their advantage to alter their regulations so as to permit of my making a book in the Paddock." - [Making a Book at Brooklands](https://www.motorsportmagazine.com/archive/article/april-1925/21/making-book-brooklands) - _Motor Sport_ magazine, April 1925

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks, I was not aware of that.

Comment: I must say I think the idea of on-course betting at motor races is weird.